# Wifi not working in kubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu

I installed Kubuntu 18.04 as a dual boot with Windows 10, recently, on my Dell Inspiron 3543.
Bluetooth is working fine, but Wi-Fi is not working.
I have tried almost every possible fix available in the internet, but still could not have it up and running.
Ethernet is working fine.
And wifi works fine in Windows 10.

I have Broadcom Wi-Fi card.

[image: Snapshot of Information from kubuntu Driver Manager]
[image: System Information]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) having Secure Boot disabled is part of the most popular answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is secure boot enabled on the laptop BIOS?  That can definitely prevent it from working.  I actually had the same Broadcom card in my laptop and disabling secure boot fixed the problem.

Comment: I will give that a try

Comment: -_-  ............. It worked.

Comment: Does turning it off cause any problem?

Comment: It's a security measure against malware and other system attacks.  I've never enabled it before (on purpose).  It's more relevant to Windows systems.

Comment: Okay and thank you so much for the help.