# Wifi not working on Kubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, asus

My Kubuntu doesn't recognized my wifi card:

`lspci` outputs non about my wifi but `lshw -C network` does, it shows that I have an Intel card with chipset `iwlwifi`

I have tried to enable the module `iwlwifi` with `modprobe iwlwifi` but it didn't help. When I `lsmod` it shows `0` on the third third column. I followed the instructions here:
[Wi-Fi Not Working on Ubuntu? Here’s How to Fix it](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-wi-fi-not-working-ubuntu/).

I also tries to disable Secure boot as written here: [Wifi not working in kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145706/wifi-not-working-in-kubuntu), but it didn't help either. I have ASUS motherboard, it now shows "secure boot: setup" after resetting the the keys.

what should I do? I updated my BIOS to latest version by asus but it didn't help. I'm mentioning that when I tried Kubuntu live before installing the wifi worked.

Comment: What is the Kubuntu version? What is the Wireless device?

Comment: @Pilot6 Kubuntu version is the LST (20.04) and the wifi card WiFi 6 AX200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will come here in the future, The last BIOS version from ASUS (1004) fixed the problem.

I was needed to execute `modprobe iwlwifi` after updating the BIOS.